# On shortcut ctrl+space on keyboard, space is added in text area and input boxes in chrome app mode

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press ctrl+space, space gets added automatically in text area and input box in the end when the webpage having text area is opened in chrome app mode.

The issue started happening in chrome version 116.0.5845.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

To reproduce the issue Run the following through command prompt:

For example:
(App mode)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea" - Issue is reproducible

(Regular browser)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea - issue is not reproducible

On pressing ctrl+space, it should not add additional space in text area in the end

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can report it in https://crbug.com if it's not reported yet.